# Is there a way to a script know using GAS Maps Service the city in which the user is?

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script

Is there a way to a script know using Google Apps Script Maps Service  (with the permission of the user, of course) the city in which the user is to insert this information into the user spreadsheet?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear but if you are talking about a spreadsheet you can try  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var locale = ss.getSpreadsheetLocale()
 var timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()
 Logger.log(locale + " " + timezone)  `    although the results of this do not guarantee where the data was inserted into the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google apps script runs in the server so is not aware of location of user at a point in time. If you need the location as data in a script, you can obtain it using javascript in the browser and pass it as a calling parameter to the apps script. see this reference for html5 code to get location http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp